# How to convert timestamp to another datatype?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to use df.iloc[] to locate a particular cell in dataframe. But we are unable to do it bcoz the cell contains date in timestamp format. I guess we need to convert that into int or string or float type. How do we do this?

Answer (score 0):

that depends on the condition that that row is supposed to answer.
if you are looking for a specific range of dates try this :

```
dates=pd.date_range(A,Z)
day1DF= LWeekDF.ix[(LWeekDF['ReportTime']>=dates[A]) & (LWeekDF['ReportTime']<=dates[1])]
```

you now have a data frame with rows that answer to that condition.
this will work with other conditions as well.
if the dates are giving you problems try this

```
A=pd.datetime.date(a)
```